# How can I include javascript not moduled without using eval()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to include a javascript file into a main file.
Unlike C/C++, where #include means "include all variables and functions", export/import and module.exports are only suitable for moduled files.
How can I implement the one of C/C++ in javascript without using eval()? Here's an example.

header.js

```
var a = 1;
function b(){};
```

main.js

```
// How can I include header.js?
console.log(a);
console.log(b());
```

Comment: What do you mean by "moduled file"? What is wrong with using modules?

Comment: What environment are you in? Clientside js in browsers, serverside node.js, something else?

Comment: In C/C++ `#include` basically means "paste the whole file contents (mostly function declarations) here", and you have modularisation by scopes per compilation unit. You don't want to that kind of includes in JavaScript.

Comment: If this is in a browser, you can easily do it the old fashioned way with `<script src="header.js"></script>` followed by `<script src="main.js"></script>` in your HTML. Global variables are shared among all script tags.

Comment: @RiddleAaron In Node.js, you can use `module.exports = { b };` and `const { b } = require('./header')`

Comment: @Bergi Yes, pasting the whole file is what I want to do. And I'm serverside node.js. Moduled file means a file that uses export clause in ES6 or exports in node.js. I don't know what word means such files.

Comment: @JLRishe How about plural variable and functions?

Comment: @RiddleAaron But if you were to include `header.js` in multiple files, you would get multiple instances of your variables/functions?! Or even worse, you'd get name collisions between them. Why not use ordinary imports/exports?

Comment: @RiddleAaron Yes, you can use the same technique for as many variables and functions as you want.